# Omnioutliner replacement for time estimation in windows

Tags: estimation, outliner

I used to use OmniOutliner to do quick time estimates but as it is mac only I need a windows replacement for work.

Here's my use case:
I want to be able to break down my projects into sub-tasks with work hour estimates that can be rolled up to each parent in the hierarchy. (the bold italic font indicates a calculated field).

- ```
  total              ***42h***
  ```
- ```
  task 1             ***23h***
  ```

  - ```
    subtask 1.1     3h
    ```
  - ```
    subtask 1.2    20h
    ```
- ```
  task 2             ***19h***
  ```

  - ```
    subtask 2.1    16h
    ```
  - ```
    subtask 2.2     ***3h***
    ```
  - ```
    subtask 2.2.1   3h
    ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please make use of superuser.com for questions like this not related to programming.

Comment: I'm using this for project time estimation for my programming tasks.  Essentially I want a simple project management system for my own use to explain my time lines to management.  Is this not appropriate for SO?